# Pandas create column conditional on others

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tag':['x','x','z','z','x','z'], 'val':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})
```

Is there a one-liner to add a column 'res' that shows -val if tag=='x' otherwise +val, so it would look like

```
  tag  val  res
0   x    1   -1
1   x    2   -2
2   z    3    3
3   z    1    1
4   x    2   -2
5   z    3    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do:

```
# ... 
import numpy as np
df['res'] = np.where(df['tag'] == 'x', -df['val'], df['val'])
```

Answer (score 2):

By manipulating the boolean Series `df.tag != 'x'`

```
df['res'] = df.tag.ne('x').mul(2).sub(1).mul(df.val)

df
#  tag  val  res
#0   x    1   -1
#1   x    2   -2
#2   z    3    3
#3   z    1    1
#4   x    2   -2
#5   z    3    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `apply`:

```
df['res'] = df.apply(
              lambda x: x['val'] if not x['tag'] == 'x' else (-1 * x['val']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `np.where`

```
df['res']=np.where(df.tag=='x',-df.val,df.val)
df
Out[271]: 
  tag  val  res
0   x    1   -1
1   x    2   -2
2   z    3    3
3   z    1    1
4   x    2   -2
5   z    3    3
```